# Use Trillian with Live Messenger?

Tags: windows-live-messenger, trillian

I installed trillian astra, and it's prompting me for an Astra account signin. However I just want to use it with my Live Messenger account. How can I do this? Am i supposed to just enter my email address and password into the account name and password fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trillian Astra requires that you register an Astra account:

http://forums.ceruleanstudios.com/showthread.php?t=96784

> It wanted me to registered for an Astra account. Is this really
>   required? v3 and earlier didn't. I
>   only need it for IM and chats with the
>   popular services (ICQ, AIM, MSN, IRC,
>   YM, Jabber, etc.).
>
> It's required.
>
> Registering sets pass and info to log in to astra messenger as well as set account for 30 > day trial and web access

**Edit:**

Under the "Features" list:

> **One Login for All Accounts**
>   Securely store your identities and
>   accounts with Astra, guaranteeing you
>   access to your full profile from any
>   device or location. Your data is
>   always stored using industry-grade AES
>   encryption and is never readable by
>   anyone but you.

It's seems that it requires an Astra account in order to store your credentials for IM accounts in a central database, so that you only will be required to login to your Astra account without the need of remembering all other passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have to log in because it's webbased?

So you first have to log into Trillian, then you can fill in your account info.

I'm trying to find some info on this, but my guess is that you should just make an account (with fake info for all I care) and simply login